# How to use bootnode in private blockchain to connect to nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

I am trying to set 2 geth on same system to connect each other using `bootnode` option.

I got two different folders with same genesis file then how to initilize and start geth console to see two nodes sync.